# Nesting For Loops Example

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a problem where I have to Modify function **multiplyAll** so that it multiplies the **product** variable by each number in the sub-arrays of **arr**. Here is the code snippet:

```
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;
  // Only change code below this line
  //Here I have written this but its not working! 
      <!--
       for(product = 1; product < arr.length; product++){
       return arr[product];
      }
      -->
  // Only change code above this line
  return product;
}

// Modify values below to test your code
multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
```

Its is displaying `[3,4]` in the answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to multiply what by what exactly ? what kind of result you're expecting ?

Comment: do you want something like : [2, 12, 210] ?

Comment: multiplyAll([[1],[2],[3]]); should return 6
multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]) should return 5040
multiplyAll([[5,1],[0.2, 4, 0.5],[3, 9]]);) should return 54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your `for` loop with :

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
    {
        product *= arr[i][j] ;
    }
}
```